# Can we specify a single reference path for all projects in the solution?

Tags: c#

Is there a way where we can specify a single reference path for all projects in the solution? I have currently 40+ projects and I would like to update this in a single place.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the path is the same for all projects, then updating those paths in the solution file isn't really any harder now is it? Just use a find and replace all right? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: you mean for build events?

Comment: @Michael- How can we update the path in the solution file.

Comment: If any one knows the solution, pls share...

Comment: @Karthi, open the solution file in your text editor of choice and take a look at each `Project(` definition. There is a path there. Generally speaking this path is relative to the solution directory, and isn't usually a problem because the projects are subdirectories, but it appears in your case it's not that cut and dry so you'll see the commonalities in the paths. Issue a basic find and replace.

Comment: and you want ALL the soulutions to do same thing pre/post build?